# How to create a addressbook and contacts

Tags: ios, addressbook

I have created a code for Addressbook and contacts where display the contacts.It was working properly but suddenly getting Run time error .As I'm new to ios .I'm not able to find the error can any one  in the Stack Overflow tell the error.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
 [super viewDidLoad];
 self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
 self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(gotohomepage:)]autorelease];
   ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
[[picker navigationBar] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
// Display only a person's phone, email, and birthdate
NSArray *displayedItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonPhoneProperty],nil];


picker.displayedProperties = displayedItems;
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
[picker release];


}
- (IBAction)gotohomepage:(id)sender
{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{


ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();

int i;
NSString *strName = @"";
NSString* company = @"";
NSString *address = @"";
NSString *suburb = @"";
NSString *postalcode = @"";
NSString *state = @"";
NSString *country = @"";
NSString *mobile = @"";
NSString *phone = @"";
NSString *emailid = @"";


strName = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyCompositeName((ABRecordRef) person);
CFStringRef name = ABRecordCopyCompositeName((ABRecordRef) person);
company  = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue((ABRecordRef) person, kABPersonOrganizationProperty);

NSArray*  allPeople = (NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyPeopleWithName(addressBook,name);
CFRelease(name);

for (i = 0; i < [allPeople count]; i++)
{
    ABRecordRef record = [allPeople objectAtIndex:i];

    ABMutableMultiValueRef multiValue = ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonAddressProperty);
    for(CFIndex i=0; i<ABMultiValueGetCount(multiValue); i++)
    {
        NSString* HomeLabel = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(multiValue, i);
        if([HomeLabel isEqualToString:@"_$!<Home>!$_"])
        {
            CFDictionaryRef dict = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiValue, i);
            address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kABPersonAddressStreetKey)];
            suburb = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kABPersonAddressCityKey)];
            postalcode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kABPersonAddressZIPKey)];
            state = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kABPersonAddressStateKey)];
            country = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kABPersonAddressCountryKey)];

            CFRelease(dict);
        }
        CFRelease(HomeLabel);
    }
    CFRelease(multiValue);
}
CFRelease(allPeople);


ABMultiValueRef phones =(NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
NSString* mobileLabel = nil;
for(CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(phones); i++)
{
    mobileLabel = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phones, i);
    if([mobileLabel isEqualToString:(NSString *)kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel])
    {
        mobile = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, i);
        NSLog(@"phone   %@",mobile);
    }
    else if ([mobileLabel isEqualToString:(NSString*)kABPersonPhoneIPhoneLabel])
    {
        phone = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, i);
        NSLog(@"phone   %@",phone);

        CFRelease(mobileLabel);
        break ;
    }
    CFRelease(mobileLabel);

}
CFStringRef value, label;
ABMutableMultiValueRef multi = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
CFIndex count = ABMultiValueGetCount(multi);
if (count == 1)
{
    value = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, 0);
    emailid = (NSString*) value;
    NSLog(@"self.emailID   %@",emailid);
    CFRelease(value);
}
else
{
    for (CFIndex i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        label = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(multi, i);
        value = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, i);

        // check for Work e-mail label
        if (CFStringCompare(label, kABWorkLabel, 0) == 0)
        {
            emailid = (NSString*) value;
            NSLog(@"self.emailID   %@",emailid);
        }
        else if(CFStringCompare(label, kABHomeLabel, 0) == 0)
        {
            emailid = (NSString*) value;
            NSLog(@"self.emailID   %@",emailid);
        }

        CFRelease(label);
        CFRelease(value);
    }
}
CFRelease(multi);    
CFRelease(phones);
CFRelease(addressBook);

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

return NO;

}
```

Comment: Getting error in main as Thread1:signal SIGABRT

Answer (score 1):

On iOS6, apple introduce new privacy control, user can control the accessment of contact and calender by each app. So, in the code side, you need to add some way to request the permission. In iOS5 or before, we can always call

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
```

to get the addressbook without any problem, but in iOS6, if you don't have permission, this call will just return empty pointer. That why we need to change the method to get ABAddressBookRef.

This type of error generally appears when permission is not granted to access address book.In that case please add this piece of code

```
__block BOOL accessGranted = NO;
if (ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion != NULL) { // we're on iOS 6
    dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
        accessGranted = granted;
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
    });
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    dispatch_release(sema);   
}
else { // we're on iOS 5 or older
    accessGranted = YES;
}

if (accessGranted) {
    // Do whatever you want here.
}
```

courtesy :- http://programmerjoe.blogspot.in/2012/10/ios6-permissions-contacts.html

If this doesn't solves your problem ping me back..

Answer (score 0):

Error is that, because on IOS6 , Apple added some features that no one have permissions to get contents  without owner's permission.